# Powershell: Looking for a fast way to do a find & replace on a text file using a csv file as the input

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, find

I have a requirement to redact log files before sending them to be analysed by a vendor. Due to the dynamic nature of the platform I support I have to generate the list dynamically. This bit is fine.

E.g. I generate a CSV file which has approx 500 rows which looks like:

```
"Node","Redaction"
"Server1","Redacted-Node-1"
"Server2.domain.local","Redacted-Node-2"
"Server3","Redacted-Node-3"
etc
```

I use this file as `$redactions = Import-Csv $nodeRedactions`

The script runs through redactions file to get the find&replace pairs, then does a find/replace on the target file. E.g. Server1 is replaced with Redacted-Node-1.

$fullpath is the path to the text file currently being processed using this code:

```
$redactions = Import-Csv $nodeRedactions 
$fileContent = Get-Content $fullpath
$n = 1
foreach ($row in $redactions)

{ 
    #Write-Host $n + " " + $fullpath
    $field1 = $row.Node 
    $field2 = $row.Redaction
    $fileContent = $fileContent | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $field1,$field2}
    #$n= $n + 1 
}
#Create the output file complete with redactions
$fileContent | Out-File $outputFile
```

This works perfectly well for small files. But when running on a file that has 50,000 rows it takes about 1 second to run the find and replace on each row. Is there a faster way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use a hashtable for fast lookups between `Node` and `Redaction` values in combination with a [regex pattern and a match evaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)), or [**Replacement with a script block in PowerShell 7+**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-with-a-script-block), that uses this hashtable for replacements.

```
$map = @{}
Import-Csv $nodeRedactions | ForEach-Object {
    $map[$_.Node] = $_.Redaction
}

$re = [regex]::new(
    '(?:{0})' -f ($map.Keys.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'),
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions] 'Compiled, IgnoreCase')

$content = Get-Content $fullPath -Raw
$re.Replace($content, { $map[$args[0].Value] }) | Set-Content $outputFile

# NOTE: In PowerShell 7+ you can use:
(Get-Content $fullPath -Raw) -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] } |
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

Worth noting, the above approach will get the content of `$fullPath` in memory before replacing it and storing it in the `$outputFile`, if you need to preserve memory then for *line-by-line* processing I would recommend:

```
$map = @{}
Import-Csv $nodeRedactions | ForEach-Object {
    $map[$_.Node] = $_.Redaction
}

$re = [regex]::new(
    '(?:{0})' -f ($map.Keys.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'),
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions] 'Compiled, IgnoreCase')

[System.IO.File]::ReadLines($fullPath) |
    ForEach-Object { $re.Replace($_, { $map[$args[0].Value] }) } |
    Set-Content $outputFile

# NOTE: In PowerShell 7+ you can use:
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines($fullPath) |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] } } |
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

---

Due to feedback in comments, adding this alternative which should improve performance even further using an anonymous function:

```bash
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines($fullPath) | & {
    begin {
        $map = @{}
        Import-Csv $nodeRedactions | ForEach-Object {
            $map[$_.Node] = $_.Redaction
        }

        $re = [regex]::new(
            '(?:{0})' -f ($map.Keys.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'),
            [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions] 'Compiled, IgnoreCase')
    }

    process {
        # NOTE: In PowerShell 7+ you can use:
        # $_ -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] }

        $re.Replace($_, { $map[$args[0].Value] })
    }
} | Set-Content $outputFile
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good point, updated, thanks

Comment: This is much faster than the way I was doing it but still pretty slow. On production data there's approx 3500 redactions to be checked and replaced if found. On file with 4000 lines it takes about 8.5 mins with the line by line approach being slightly quicker. Is this as fast as I can hope for?

Comment: Are you sure the first approach using `-Raw` is slower? It shouldn't but it should definitely consume more memory @BaldFeegle otherwise I don't see much room from improvement, `Regex.Replace` with a `MatchEvaluator` is slow by itself however you could improve performance by rewriting your code in C#

Comment: Timed using the same input file -Raw came in at 8 min 32secs, line-by-line 8 min 02 secs. I guess I could try using C#, but that would require learning C# in the first place and getting somewhere to run it in our environment.

Comment: @BaldFeegle in the line-by-line approach, try changing `ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] } }` for `& { process { $_ -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] } } }` that should improve the speed even further but other than that I don't think it can be improved more

Comment: @BaldFeegle see my latest edit, that's the best I can think of

Comment: Thanks for all of your help with this, sadly the latest version is the slowest so far on my test files. With your help though I've got something that's at least 10 times faster than the thing I crafted myself. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of reading the entire file into memory and then attempting to replace each node name *in all the strings*, flip it around so you only read 1 line at a time and then perform every possible substitution on that before writing it to disk:

```
$redactions = Import-Csv $nodeRedactions 

Get-Content $fullpath |ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($row in $redactions) {
    # make all the required substitutions
    $_ = $_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($row.Node)),$row.Redaction
  }
  # output to the pipeline
  $_
} | Out-File $outputFile
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I get an out of memory error implementing this.

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At D:\PS_Scripts\Autoredact\AutoRedact_28_11_2023_2.ps1:154 char:24
+     $_ = $_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($row.Node)),$row.Redaction
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Checked and powershell is set to allow the maximum memory.